# How do you "start server" in JavaDB even if I close the netbeans?

Tags: java, database, if-statement

I have created a program using Java DB or database, the last thing that I want is to run the program with out clicking the "start server" in Java DB I want the server need to run along with program I created. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your application is deployed on the server, you can run the app any time after starting the server (from command-line) and pointing your browser at "http://localhost:8080/app_name"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a jar file for your project. if you are using java embedded Database it is a part of Java Virtual Machine. and the jar file you have created is a product.  No client server model is needed for this.
for netbeans go to `Run->Clean and build project` to create Jar file and then go to project folder to check it. And you are no more need to connect database separately.